# Unable to render Strsuts2-jQuery Plugin Ajax response into HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, struts2

I'am Strust2-Jquery Plugin in my application. Everything is running fine so far till i stuck into this issue. I 'm using `sj:a` tag to submit a from to the server, in case of error the server returns a html formatted error that i display to the user. I'm using the following code
(a simplified version)

```
$.subscribeeventHandler' , function(event, data){

    var $res = $(event.originalEvent.request.responseText);
    alert(event.originalEvent.request.responseText);
    $('#recoverPasswordErrorMsg').html($res.html());

});
```

In the alert it displays the correct html but when i set the html it displays the html string rather parsing and displaying it. the following string is displayed on the page

"<strong>Your account is currently inactive. Please activate your account by clicking the link sent to user1741@dummy.com </strong>"

Comment: Is it possible that what's being returned is being returned as &lt; and &gt; tags encasing the strong param?

Comment: if it is the case then what will be the possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using s:actionerro tag to display the message from the server side, basically this tag was escaping the HTMl as it has a property `escape` and its value is true by default. I changed the value of `escape` to `false` and it worked for me perfectly.

Comment: Oh I forgot. I am a newbie here, you know